# Program output with nested function and function parameter

Tags: python, function, closures, nested-function

Given the following code

```
def alpha(num, proc):

    def beta(): print(num)

    if num == 1:
        alpha(2, beta)
    else:
        proc()

def gamma():
    pass

alpha(1, gamma)
```

I expected the output to be 2, since my logic was:

```
   alpha(1, gamma)
=> alpha(2, beta)  # since num == 1
=> proc()          # since num != 1
=> beta()
=> print(2)        # since beta was a parameter alongside 2
```

However, the actual output is code is 1. Could anyone please explain why this is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `alpha(1, gamma)` is called, `alpha(2, beta)` is called since `num` is equal to `1`. Here, it passes a reference to the `beta` function currently defined inside this invocation of the `alpha` function which holds a closure over the values of the parameters. Thus this `beta` function sees the value of `num` as the value before the next invocation of `alpha`, so `1` is printed later. If you also add `print(proc)` inside `beta`, you'll see that `proc` is equal to the `gamma` function which was first passed to `alpha`.

Comment: See also https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/closure for more information.